# How to communicate between UI app and an Helper App

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a main application. Now I need to add upload capability. I thought of using a helper app which runs in dock so that even if the main app is closed it continues to upload. Now my problem is that I need to feed the file paths to the helper app so that it can start uploading.

How can I send message to the helper app from the main app ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Unix Domain Sockets](http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html), or perhaps [Distributed Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), if you want a Cocoa specific framework.

Comment: NSDistributionCenter works like a charm. Is there any chance of app rejection by using this ?

Comment: With Apple, who knows?(!). Just be aware that most of the functions state this: "Sandboxed apps can send notifications only if they do not contain a dictionary. If the sending application is in an App Sandbox, userInfo must be nil."

Comment: That warning is there for `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:` selector. Atleast for now I can assume that `postNotificationName:object:` can be safely used right ?

Comment: It sounds like a reasonable assumption.